# How to read data via a URL with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to make my online app communicate with Facebook. According to their documentation in order to authenticate my users I need to redirect them to the oAuth dialog, with this URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

So far so good. If the user grants me permission Facebook will redirect him to the URL I specified on my request, appending a code to it. Like this:

```
http://YOUR_URL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER
```

**Question**: how do I read that code with my PHP script?

Comment: Since the answer posted below is the correct one, will you remove your edit and accept Sarfraz's answer? Doing so will improve the question clarity for future site visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`$_GET`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp):

```
echo $_GET['code'];
```

Answer (score 1):

So the response URL should be like http://youdomain.com/controller.php?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER

in your controller.php

```
$_REQUEST['code']
```